# Main function terminates before coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm working on a project in a course in process oriented programming.

I'm trying to launch two objects (a producer and consumer) in a coroutine, and then let a producer get consumed. I then tell the main function to wait for the coroutine to finish with Job.join(). However, this doesn't seem to work. Because the invokeOnCompletion function is executed before produce/consume cycle has even started. I've included the code and output below and would appreciate any input.

This is project in a course in process oriented programming. The ultimate goal is to spawn multiple object instances and let them communicate using channels. I've never written code in kotlin before and have never used coroutines. Is this even possible, or have I misinterpreted coroutines?

```
class Producer(val idvar: Int) {
    var resource: Int = 10

    init {
        println("${idvar} was created.")
    }

    suspend fun getConsumed(channel: Channel<Int>) = produce<Int> {
        println("Someone is trying to consume me...")
        while(true) {
            channel.send(1)
            resource--
            println("I have ${resource} things left.")
            if(resource <= 0) {
                break
            }
            var sleep = ((Random().nextDouble())*1000).toLong()
            println("sleeping for ${sleep} ms")
            delay(1000)

        }
        println("I'm used up! I have ${resource} resources.")

    }
}

class Consumer() {
    var resource: Int = 0

    suspend fun consume(producer: Producer?, channel: Channel<Int>) = produce<Int> {
        println("Trying to consume producer: ${producer?.resource}")
        producer?.getConsumed(channel)
        while(true) {
            var recv = channel.receive()
            if(recv == 0) break
            resource += recv
        }
        println("Consumed in total: " + resource)
    }
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking<Unit> {

    val prodJob = launch {
        var prodObj: Producer = Producer(1)
        var consumObj: Consumer = Consumer()
        val chan = Channel<Int>()
        consumObj.consume(prodObj, chan)

        // Why does this println print before the above line is complete?
        println("Comsumption done.")
    }

    // invokeOnCompletion is executed before production/consumption is done?
    prodJob.invokeOnCompletion { println("Consumption is done?") }

    // Main could do other stuff here. 

    // Since prodJob is regarded as complete, main joins instantly.
    prodJob.join()
    println("Joined...")
}
```

The output is:

```
1 was created.
Comsumption done.
Trying to consume producer: 10
Consumption is done?
Someone is trying to consume me...
I have 9 things left.
sleeping for 310 ms
Joined...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Consumer.consume()`-Method is incorrect. Remove the `=produce<Int>` part and it will work:

```
suspend fun consume(producer: Producer?, channel: Channel<Int>) {
    println("Trying to consume producer: ${producer?.resource}")
    producer?.getConsumed(channel)
    while(true) {
        var recv = channel.receive()
        if(recv == 0) break
        resource += recv
    }
    println("Consumed in total: " + resource)
}
```

BTW: The `Producer.getConsumed()`-Method uses `=produce<Int>`in the wrong way. `produce` creates a new channel that is never used. It only happens to work due some internal implementation detail of the `produce`-Method. You should use `launch` to start the second Coroutine explicitly.

```
suspend fun getConsumed(channel: Channel<Int>) = launch {
    println("Someone is trying to consume me...")
    while(true) {
        channel.send(1)
        resource--
        println("I have ${resource} things left.")
        if(resource <= 0) {
            break
        }
        var sleep = ((Random().nextDouble())*1000).toLong()
        println("sleeping for ${sleep} ms")
        delay(1000)

    }
    println("I'm used up! I have ${resource} resources.")

}
```